# Why isn't the execution going insider forEach loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, fetch-api

**Execution is not entering forEach loop inside useEffect**

I am using fetch to fetch json data form api and when the user is received i am trying to execute a forEach loop but execution is not reaching inside

And can i call fuction insider then like below

And are both fetch requests going to run synchronously or they are running at the same time if so then how to make useEffect synchronous

Code attached below:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import RideDetails from "./RideDetails";

const Rides = () => {
  const [rides, setRides] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [updatedRides, setUpdatedRides] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/rides', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    } 
    }).then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok){
        throw new Error('Unable to fetch Rides data');
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      setRides(result);
      setUpdatedRides(result);
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    })

    fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/user', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok){
        throw new Error('Unable to fetch User');
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      setUser(result);
      updatedRides.forEach((updatedRide) => {
        console.log('inside forEach loop')
        updatedRide.distance = calculateDistance(updatedRide.station_path, user.station_code);
      })
      console.log('UpdatedRides', updatedRides);
    })
  }, [])

  function calculateDistance (path, user_station) {
    console.log('Inside cal')
    let min = Math.abs(user_station - path[0]);
    for(let i = 0; i<path.length; i++){
      if(path[i] === user_station){
        return 0;
      }
      if(Math.abs(path[i] - user_station) < min){
        min = Math.abs(path[i] - user_station);
      }
    }
    return min;
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Navbar user = {user}/>
      <div className="rides">
        {updatedRides.map((ride) => {
          return (
            <div className="rideDetail">
              <img src = {ride.map_url} alt="Ride_map" />
              <div>
                <p>Ride Id : {ride.id}</p>
                <p>Origin Station : {ride.origin_station_code}</p>
                <p>Station Path : {ride.station_path}</p>
                <p>Date : {ride.date}</p>
                <p>Distance : {ride.distance}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Rides;
```

Comment: "then how to make useEffect synchronous" - you can't make asynchronous code synchronous, obviously. You have race condition here and need to chain promises properly. It's easier to write this with async/await but this still requires to be aware of how promises work

Comment: It looks to be a stale closure problem. `updatedRides` still holds the original value even though you've set it to something else earlier. It will not be set to it's new value until the next render, so there is no way to use it from inside the same `useEffect` that updates it